# Avoid using two variables to send variable information to Runnable

Tags: android

I'm trying to send a variable string to Runnable, but find myself having to create two variables for this. One normal string **content** and one final string **finalcontent** that is assigned the content of the other string.

```
String content = "";
try {
    content = response.body().string();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle exception
}
final String finalcontent = content;
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText(finalcontent);
    }
});
```

Is this the normal way to do this or is there a better way to avoid creating two variables?

Comment: This is the normal way to pass a reference to a variable from an outer class to an anonymous inner class.  However, you could make use of AsyncTask which allows you to parameterize the initialization data, the progress data, and the result data the way you'd like.

Comment: Well, what would happen if there was an IOException when "content" was gathered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's limitation of Java language design but you should be able to write

```
final String content;
try {
    content = response.body().string();
} catch (IOException e) {
    content = "";
    // Handle exception
}
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText(content);
    }
});
```

Comment: To expound a bit on this answer, declaring a variable as final prevents the reference from being set to something else between the time that it was set and the time it is accessed by the code inside the run method.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a custom implementation of Runnable, here is an example

```
void foo(){
    String content = "";
    try {
        content = response.body().string();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
    runOnUiThread(new MyCustomRunnable(content));
}

private class MyCustomRunnable implements Runnable {
    private String content;

    public MyCustomRunnable(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if (text != null) {
            text.setText(content);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use RxJava?I think you just want to update UI after you get data from internet.

```
Observable observable = Observable.create(OnSubscribe()...)
.subscribeOn(Shceduler.io).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainthread)
```